# Button click sticks in active state and wont change until click function completes (workaround?)

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-events

I have this button making an ajax call using a click event. My goal is to make it so that the text inside the button changes from "submit" to "loading..." when I make that ajax call. The problem is that for some reason I can't change the text (or even hide the button) inside of the anonymous function I stick in the `.click()` method until after all the code is executed. Or at least there is no noticeable effect until the ajax call is completed and instead just sticks in the active state of the button.

I turned `async: false` in my `$.ajax` call which is making it take a while to complete everything in the click event. I think I need it this way though for reasons I could go into if necessary. The reason I bring this up is because the solution I'm looking for should change the text before the ajax call in a synchronous fashion.

Here's a simplified version of the jQuery I'm using:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).text('loading');//changing text BEFORE the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.jsfiddle.net/',
        data: {foo: 'bar'},
        async: false
    });
    $(this).text('Send Request');
});​
```

Here's a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJzzn/1/) showing exactly what I mean.

Can I do it this way or do I need to approach this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I finally got what you were talking about.  Here's what you can do to have the text change before the ajax starts.  Use setTimeout then use the success function to set it back

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text('loading');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                foo: 'bar',
              delay: 3
            },
            async: false,           
            success: function(){
                 $this.text('Send Request');  
            }
        });
    },100);      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uJzzn/11/

Comment: That's very nice, but I do actually need it to be synchronous unless I rewrite a lot of code, which I really don't want to do. I'll definitely keep this in mind next time though.

Comment: You can change async back to false.. it still works how you want it to @kevinbeal

Comment: @kevinbeal  I updated with a new idea which will force text to be changed first

Comment: @kevinbeal scratch that last one.. it didn't work also.. Here's how to make it work.. You just have to delay the ajax call for a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Use [.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [.ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) event handlers

```
$('a').click(function(){

    $(this).ajaxStart(function(){
       $(this).html('loading');
     });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {foo: 'bar'}
    });
    $(this).ajaxStop(function(){
       $(this).html('Send Request');
     });
});​
```

Comment: @kevinbeal i tested before i posted. actually it might not work because of `url`, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/uJzzn/10/ (and I've made an edits in my answer

Comment: It doesn't work with `async:false` though. I've never heard of these methods before. They will come in handy later on.